# What does the following regular expression match for?

Tags: regex

For what sample Url's does the following `req.url.match(/^\/node\//` match?

I couldn't find the expression in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp and other resources i was following so, had to put it up to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches the string `/node/`, which must be at the beginning of the string.

1. The first and last `/` are the regex delimiters.
2. The `^` matches the beginning of the string.
3. The `\/` escapes the `/` to match `/`.
4. The `node` matches the exact string `node`.

Answer (score 4):

The `^` matches the start of the string, and `\/node\/` matches `/node/`. Thus, the overall regex matches any string that begins with `/node/`.